# Laravel Orchid: How can a PostListScreen.php be reloaded after running a function from it that saves a lot to the database?

Tags: database, laravel, function, reload

Laravel Orchid: How can a PostListScreen.php be reloaded after running a function from it that saves a lot to the database?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
return back();
//or
return redirect()->back();
```

or

```
// by named route you denife in routes/platform
return redirect()->route('platform.post.list');
```

Comment: Note that redirect()->route() not refreshing page because of using Turbo ajax methods in Orchid